# Calcular duración entre dos Fechas (Minutos) en Power BI

Tags: powerbi

Requiero calcular la duración entre dos fechas solo tomando en cuenta el tiempo laboral en Power BI. Coloco un ejemplo:

*Definido un Horario laboral de 9am a 5pm*

```
Fecha Inicio           Fecha Final             Duración 
2019/03/01 2:00pm      2019/03/02 10:00am      **20 Horas**
```

Pero si tomamos en cuenta el horario laboral deberia indicar que la duración es apenas de **4 Horas**.

Agradezco la colaboración.

Comment: DAX o Power Query? Qué intentaste hasta ahora? Sábados y domingos incluidos?

Answer (score 0):

Saludos podrias hacer algo así:

```
Tiempo Diferencia = DATEDIFF('miTabla'[Fecha Inicio], Table[Fecha Final], DAY)
```

Para mayor detalle te sugiero la documentacion: [DATEDIFF](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dax/datediff-function-dax)

Comment: gracias por la respuesta. Lo que sucede es que la diferencia de tiempo que requiero obtener no es continuo, como lo hace la función sugerida DATEDIFF.  Ocupo omitir una fracción del tiempo para considerar unicamente el tiempo en un horario laboral definido.